# Nginx permanent 301 via return fails

Tags: nginx

I don't want to use rewrite but return.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on;
    server_name xyz;

    root /home/admin/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location = /blog/our-journey {
      return 301 /blog/our-journey/
    } // <- unexpected "}"
}
```

Why is this failing with the error message:
`unexpected "}"` as shown above? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> return 301 /blog/our-journey/
> ```

You're missing the semicolon `;` at the end of the preceding directive:

```
return 301 /blog/our-journey/;
```